# Pandas combine multiple subplots with same x axis into 1 bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am looping through a list containing 6 col_names. I loop by taking 3 cols at a time so i can print 3 subplots per iteration later. 
I have 2 dataframes with same column names so they look identical except for the histograms of each column name.

I want to plot similar column names of both dataframes on the same subplot. Right now, im plotting their histograms on 2 separate subplots.

currently, for col 'A','B','C' in df_plot:

[image]

and for col 'A','B','C' in df_plot2:
[image]

I only want 3 charts where i can combine similar column names into same chart so there is blue and yellow bars in the same chart.

Adding `df_plot2` below doesnt work. i think im not defining my second `axs` properly but im not sure how to do that.

```
col_name_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
chunk_list = [col_name_list[i:i + 3] for i in xrange(0, len(col_name_list), 3)]
    for k,g in enumerate(chunk_list):
        df_plot = df[g]
        df_plot2 = df[g][df[g] != 0]

        fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(g),figsize = (50,20))
        axs = axs.ravel()

        for j,x in enumerate(g):
            df_plot[x].value_counts(normalize=True).head().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs[j], position=0, title = x, fontsize = 30)
            # adding this doesnt work.
            df_plot2[x].value_counts(normalize=True).head().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs[j], position=1, fontsize = 30)
                axs[j].title.set_size(40)
        fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to plot on the same `ax`:

change `axs[j] to axs`

```
for k,g in enumerate(chunk_list):
    df_plot = df[g]
    df_plot2 = df[g][df[g] != 0]

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,len(g),figsize = (50,20))
    axs = axs.ravel()

    for j,x in enumerate(g):
        df_plot[x].value_counts(normalize=True).head().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs, position=0, title = x, fontsize = 30)
        # adding this doesnt work.
        df_plot2[x].value_counts(normalize=True).head().plot(kind='bar',ax=axs, position=1, fontsize = 30)
            axs[j].title.set_size(40)
    fig.tight_layout()
```

then just call `plt.plot()`

> Example this will plot x and y on the same subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 20, 2)

ax = plt.subplot(1,1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(x)
ax.plot(y)

plt.show()
```

EDIT:

There is now a squeeze keyword argument. This makes sure the result is always a 2D numpy array.

```
fig, ax2d = subplots(2, 2, squeeze=False)
```

if needed Turning that into a 1D array is easy:

```
axli = ax1d.flatten()
```

Comment: i get this error:  `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'`